# My Tobit model gives all infinite standard deviations

Tags: r, standard-error, tobit-regression

I am trying to do a Tobit estimation (in R) because my dependent variable ranges from 0-100 with many values at a 100.

```
# A tibble: 55,070 x 32
    DEPVAR Profit   CTR c242a1 Criminal Prison Riskaversion reciprocity1c  A098   A101  A102 incidence_gov_f~ incidence_eth_f~ warhist
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl>
 1   100  2.35e 8    35      3        0      0         1.39        2.86   0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
 2   100  7.48e 5    35      3        0      0         1.39        1.48   0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
 3   100 -7.42e 5    35      4        0      0         1.39        0.736  0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
 4   100 -7.42e 5    35      5        0      0         1.39        1.53   0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
 5    20  1.63e 7    35     12        0      0         1.39        0.679  0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
 6    10  1.42e10    35     12        0      0         1.39        1.85   0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
 7    15  1.79e 6    35      2        0      0         1.39        0.0151 0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
 8    18  1.00e 4    35      6        0      0         1.39        0.528  0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
 9     8  1.48e 4    35      3        0      0         1.39        1.05   0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
10     6  1.63e 7    35      1        0      0         1.39        0.796  0.610 0.0899 0.839                0                0       5
# ... with 55,060 more rows, and 18 more variables: peaceyears <dbl>, Expop <dbl>, NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD <dbl>, SI.POV.GINI <dbl>, tottax <dbl>,
#   indiv <dbl>, corp <dbl>, indirect <dbl>, gst <dbl>, trade <dbl>, tottax_d <dbl>, indiv_d <dbl>, corp_d <dbl>, indirect_d <dbl>,
#   gst_d <dbl>, trade_d <dbl>, matchcode <fct>, c241x <dbl>
```

I do however get very strange output.

My estimation looks more or less as follows:

```
tobitresult <- 

censReg(
DEPVAR ~                       
#Profit +                      
log(CTR) +                      
c242a1 +                        
as.factor(Criminal) +           
as.factor(Prison) +             
Riskaversion +                  
reciprocity1c +                  
as.factor(incidence_gov_flag) + # Cultural A
as.factor(incidence_eth_flag) + # Cultural B
warhist +                       # Cultural C
peaceyears +                    # Cultural D
Expop +                         # Cultural E
NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD +             # FE - GDP
indiv_d +                       # Tax Revenue Individual
corp_d +                        # Tax Revenue Corporate
as.factor(matchcode),
right = 100, start = NULL, data = df)

summary(tobitresult)
```

(A part) of the output looks as follows:

```
Observations:
         Total  Left-censored     Uncensored Right-censored 
         55070           1389          53681              0 

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)
(Intercept)                     0.9511556        Inf       0       1
log(CTR)                       -0.1505117        Inf       0       1
```

I have tried to google for Tobit in connection with infinite standard errors, however without succes. Does anyone have an idea what could be the issue?

```
   > dput(impX)
structure(list(matchcode = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L), 
    c241 = c(70L, 70L, 100L, 85L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    80L, 90L, 90L, 60L, 95L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 16L, 10L, 
    65L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 25L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 70L, 70L, 
    80L, 5L, 60L, 100L, 100L, 80L, 100L, 90L, 70L, 100L, 50L, 
    100L, 60L, 60L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 70L, 100L, 100L, 22L, 100L, 
    85L, 85L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 60L, 30L, 80L, 
    100L, 100L, 90L, 100L, 100L, 40L, 100L, 70L, 100L, 70L, 99L, 
    100L, 100L, 60L, 65L, 100L, 100L, 80L, 90L, 65L, 80L, 100L, 
    100L, 70L, 0L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 80L, 15L, 100L, 20L, 70L, 
    100L, 98L, 90L, 100L, 70L, 80L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 80L, 
    15L, 100L, 27L, 70L, 100L, 80L, 100L, 100L, 30L, 100L, 6L, 
    100L, 70L, 70L, 100L, 85L, 30L, 40L, 12L, 10L, 65L, 20L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    70L), Profit = c(14801L, 900L, 3209L, 771L, 500L, 271L, 7840L, 
    14902L, 71000L, 5170L, -3175L, 3407500L, -26L, 168L, 1484379L, 
    2271576L, 46518L, 56547L, 575L, 31L, 71482L, 6244L, 112532069L, 
    129L, -40L, 367L, 1400800L, 1001960L, 39273203L, 13343016L, 
    34135L, 5917740L, -44000L, 17885L, 1189907L, 150L, -285300L, 
    328L, 9082952L, NA, 13343016L, -197L, 1484379L, 335306005L, 
    29L, 112532069L, 682L, 234874952L, -49L, 31L, 5124L, 1425408L, 
    -12872L, 2349302L, 112532069L, 2879696L, 200L, 34135L, 3374L, 
    504488L, -56124245L, 198L, 16327882L, -475L, -2000L, 3560L, 
    670900L, 124L, 62L, 20164967L, 2111L, 128L, 34135L, 9082952L, 
    112532069L, NA, 728L, -65800L, 6500L, 61790L, 13929599L, 
    -33789918L, 14280L, -4101228L, 13126L, 3518L, 22849782L, 
    6556247L, 28098L, 6500L, 2601486L, 37L, 2318L, 108L, 30976056L, 
    117L, 71000L, 221760L, 870L, 100L, 87400L, 34135L, 13343016L, 
    1692700L, 3868L, 990L, 68L, 124937L, 6846L, 2205L, 700L, 
    33L, 818L, 7382L, -33789918L, 9082952L, 2473L, 5917740L, 
    -1147107L, 289259L, 495602L, 10138007L, 1189907L, 59128000L, 
    50940890L, -33789918L, 55L, 20600L, 584L, 931L, 3877996L, 
    1024L, 22377L, 1990L, 15411L, -3206450L, 24566L, 312802L, 
    34135L, 5300L, -1111L), CTR = c(35L, 20L, 23L, 35L, 30L, 
    20L, 15L, 35L, 33L, 25L, 30L, 16L, 19L, 15L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 
    24L, 10L, 34L, 25L, 17L, 17L, 25L, 35L, 15L, 35L, 25L, 30L, 
    30L, 26L, 38L, 25L, 35L, 25L, 25L, 42L, 15L, 35L, 30L, 24L, 
    35L, 33L, 15L, 35L, 32L, 31L, 31L, 25L, 25L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 
    15L, 16L, 30L, 33L, 12L, 33L, 25L, 30L, 30L, 27L, 27L, 10L, 
    25L, 15L, 27L, 31L, 31L, 35L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 
    30L, 35L, 16L, 15L, 29L, 35L, 15L, 35L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 25L, 
    25L, 10L, 16L, 19L, 30L, 12L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 33L, 27L, 27L, 
    19L, 27L, 10L, 33L, 30L, 16L, 35L, 24L, 15L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    14L, 30L, 19L, 30L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 15L, 15L, 33L, 33L, 
    30L, 25L, 28L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 25L, 30L, 33L, 15L, 33L, 28L, 
    30L, 30L, 37L, 30L), c242a1 = c(12L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 
    1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 0L, 
    30L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 
    2L, 30L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 48L, 
    8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 2L), Criminal = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L), Prison = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Riskaversion = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L), reciprocity1c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L), A098 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A101 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A102 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), incidence_gov_flag = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), incidence_eth_flag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), warhist = c(5L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
    2L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 12L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L), peaceyears = c(1L, 
    56L, 59L, 28L, 11L, 14L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 44L, 18L, 56L, 58L, 
    59L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 38L, 57L, 40L, 30L, 32L, 42L, 21L, 
    4L, 0L, 31L, 56L, 9L, 12L, 50L, 39L, 0L, 57L, 60L, 5L, 2L, 
    13L, 11L, 14L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 24L, 55L, 7L, 10L, 38L, 57L, 60L, 
    6L, 9L, 56L, 59L, 0L, 0L, 59L, 43L, 60L, 11L, 14L, 20L, 11L, 
    12L, 14L, 4L, 56L, 15L, 15L, 0L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 
    14L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 33L, 9L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 59L, 58L, 27L, 36L, 
    41L, 16L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 27L, 16L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 
    59L, 16L, 20L, 12L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 9L, 
    12L, 10L, 13L, 38L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 45L, 
    0L, 0L, 11L, 14L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 51L, 57L, 13L, 14L, 38L
    ), Expop = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD = c(4202L, 
    4754L, 5942L, 15227L, 3020L, 4769L, 4393L, 7169L, 677L, 1516L, 
    1198L, 7726L, 9126L, 10211L, 5114L, 6453L, 6927L, 9984L, 
    4438L, 9690L, 11346L, 11831L, 15773L, 3551L, 2614L, 556L, 
    8957L, 4542L, 9817L, 18189L, 21956L, 31968L, 8023L, 8911L, 
    6555L, 8110L, 6728L, 1453L, 27702L, 11590L, 16516L, 3011L, 
    4364L, 1368L, 1378L, 25577L, 5176L, 5926L, 4130L, 2888L, 
    3535L, 12283L, 14859L, 14549L, 17081L, 5305L, 3138L, 40438L, 
    7488L, 8405L, 10225L, 14259L, 1771L, 1764L, 1906L, 2110L, 
    1366L, 24196L, 3054L, 11236L, 5299L, 1588L, 10494L, 14526L, 
    10070L, 13847L, 4530L, 2195L, 2393L, 2945L, 1237L, 13437L, 
    6305L, 7759L, 1456L, 7332L, 4921L, 3166L, 11078L, 748L, 7052L, 
    679L, 2959L, 3546L, 35298L, 11688L, 5584L, 7404L, 3729L, 
    11781L, 12256L, 13895L, 22739L, 5799L, 3844L, 7179L, 9723L, 
    8029L, 11822L, 1021L, 1668L, 4856L, 5659L, 7197L, 13294L, 
    16616L, 20305L, 23945L, 6476L, 1237L, 1143L, 1268L, 1519L, 
    9330L, 10864L, 11887L, 1389L, 1695L, 969L, 1200L, 4628L, 
    6452L, 12376L, 2178L, 2288L, 2732L, 3032L, 11590L, 13437L, 
    8426L, 1804L), SI.POV.GINI = c(31L, 31L, 30L, 46L, 34L, 36L, 
    17L, 16L, 33L, 54L, 33L, 33L, 47L, 47L, 33L, 32L, 30L, 27L, 
    56L, 57L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 52L, 39L, 39L, 31L, 34L, 47L, 26L, 
    26L, 34L, 49L, 37L, 53L, 52L, 31L, 33L, 32L, 41L, 33L, 37L, 
    37L, 39L, 34L, 34L, 41L, 54L, 33L, 58L, 57L, 39L, 33L, 57L, 
    34L, 16L, 30L, 33L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 39L, 34L, 30L, 28L, 32L, 
    32L, 34L, 47L, 39L, 17L, 32L, 41L, 35L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 35L, 
    34L, 36L, 39L, 47L, 31L, 39L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 52L, 49L, 39L, 
    33L, 44L, 41L, 33L, 49L, 54L, 53L, 50L, 41L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
    38L, 53L, 34L, 30L, 29L, 37L, 41L, 41L, 33L, 50L, 45L, 32L, 
    36L, 29L, 36L, 24L, 49L, 52L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 
    33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 29L, 29L, 45L, 33L, 35L, 33L, 52L, 34L, 
    39L, 32L, 42L), tottax = c(6L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 15L, 14L, 9L, 
    10L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 18L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 23L, 19L, 22L, 18L, 
    23L, 20L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 6L, 19L, 20L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 
    18L, 13L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 22L, 20L, 19L, 14L, 17L, 
    8L, 14L, 18L, 11L, 11L, 19L, 14L, 15L, 23L, 22L, 25L, 24L, 
    9L, 17L, 24L, 23L, 24L, 13L, 23L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 6L, 
    17L, 8L, 15L, 11L, 27L, 19L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 20L, 
    23L, 10L, 9L, 20L, 18L, 11L, 21L, 16L, 11L, 17L, 10L, 27L, 
    10L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 19L, 
    10L, 13L, 17L, 18L, 23L, 25L, 11L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 23L, 18L, 
    18L, 22L, 23L, 30L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 19L, 17L, 18L, 7L, 
    8L, 10L, 10L, 19L, 21L, 18L, 22L, 22L, 18L, 12L, 18L, 17L, 
    24L, 15L), indiv = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
    6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 
    6L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
    3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 5L), corp = c(0L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L), indirect = c(4L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 
    11L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 9L, 17L, 
    13L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 14L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 
    10L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 18L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 4L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 20L, 7L, 18L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 10L, 
    7L, 9L, 10L, 24L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 
    7L, 4L, 17L, 14L, 5L, 15L, 12L, 8L, 14L, 5L, 18L, 5L, 8L, 
    9L, 0L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 9L, 17L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 24L, 
    7L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 
    13L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 8L), gst = c(1L, 9L, 
    12L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 
    9L, 11L, 17L, 6L, 15L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 
    11L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 17L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 15L, 6L, 15L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 
    4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 2L, 
    9L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 
    2L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 
    7L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 
    7L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 10L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 6L), trade = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 
    11L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), tottax_d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, -1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, -2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), indiv_d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), corp_d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), indirect_d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -4L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gst_d = c(0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, -5L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, -1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), trade_d = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
    6L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), c241x = c(30L, 30L, 0L, 15L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 40L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    84L, 90L, 35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 75L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 30L, 30L, 
    20L, 95L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 10L, 30L, 0L, 50L, 0L, 40L, 
    40L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 78L, 0L, 15L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 70L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 
    0L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 35L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 10L, 
    35L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 20L, 85L, 0L, 80L, 
    30L, 0L, 2L, 10L, 0L, 30L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 85L, 
    0L, 73L, 30L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 70L, 0L, 94L, 0L, 30L, 30L, 
    0L, 15L, 70L, 60L, 88L, 90L, 35L, 80L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 30L)), .Names = c("matchcode", "c241", 
"Profit", "CTR", "c242a1", "Criminal", "Prison", "Riskaversion", 
"reciprocity1c", "A098", "A101", "A102", "incidence_gov_flag", 
"incidence_eth_flag", "warhist", "peaceyears", "Expop", "NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD", 
"SI.POV.GINI", "tottax", "indiv", "corp", "indirect", "gst", 
"trade", "tottax_d", "indiv_d", "corp_d", "indirect_d", "gst_d", 
"trade_d", "c241x"), row.names = c(NA, -141L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002500788>)
```

EDIT: The tobit model works with a small sample. It does however never work with the original df. It currently gives the following error when doing `summary(tobitresult)`:

```
Error in printCoefmat(coef(x, logSigma = logSigma), digits = digits) : 
  'x' must be coefficient matrix/data frame
```

Comment: What I notice: The output says there is left-censoring but what you describe is right-censoring. Do you have an explanation for that or do I miss something?

Comment: That is very observant, and a mistake on my part. I have been doing some trial and error alterations (of which one was reversing the DEPVAR (y=100-y)). My apologies, I should have mentioned this.

Comment: I see that all my trial and error output have similar results; only left censoring. Could that be the issue perhaps?

Comment: Could be, but it's difficult to say without the data.

Comment: Can I add anything to the post that would help you take an educated guess?

Comment: A reproducible example would be ideal.

Comment: Would this suffice?

Comment: Unfortunatley no. A reproducible example means that everyone can re-run the model to get the exact same results as you did. You have a lot of observations which is a problem for this. A possibility would be that you select a few observations at random, say 20, that give similar results. Then post the 20 observations here.

Comment: I have added a dput of a very small sample, converting all decimals to integers.

Comment: Go through some usual debugs. Fit the variables one at a time?

Comment: This situation might also be something that the package maintainer would like to know about. What I wonder is that in the posted code it says `right=100` in the command and that is always an issue with left censoring. So you transform such that the data are left censored but specify that they are right censored at 100? I'd first look at that.

Comment: @AdamO Yes, I guess you are right. Because I did not get anything running (and the OLS worked) I thought I might have used wrong settings, but it seems it is more of a data problem. I got the first one working with the sample right now.

Comment: `censReg` has some problems.  I had to rewrite part of it a few years ago.  The purpose primarily was to extend it to include interval censoring, but I also had to include workarounds for numerical instabilities it experiences when explanatory variables with large ranges (such as dates that are internally represented in seconds since 1970).  Because you have a complex model with apparently large variation among explanatory variables, perhaps you are experiencing something similar.  What happens when you first standardize all the nonconstant columns of the model matrix?

Comment: @whuber Standardising worked like a charm.. Thank you so much! The only problem now is my `matchcode` variable, for which is still gives the same problem. Is there any workaround to include the variable `matchcode` as a factor? Could it because of the many factor levels?

Comment: That would be a good direction to investigate.  What you do depends on the extent to which you might be able to relax or modify your model.